# loading method of same controller to other method

Tags: codeigniter

I wrote a controller in which a particular method is defined to perform a specific task, let's say, for example, to load a view:

```
controller ABCDEF{

    public function abc()
    {
        ....
        $this->load->view('view_name',$common_value);
    }

    public function DEF()
    {
        $this->load-> 
        //here in place of view i want to load method abc so that view_name get loaded with all its corresponding parameters 
    }

}
```

What would the correct syntax be to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be as simple as this, or am I misundersting your question?

```
public function DEF(){
    $this->abc();
}
```